# Auto highlight the text in all textbox control in a winform upon enter(gained focus)

Tags: c#, winforms

while i know that this will do the trick

`textbox.SelectionStart = 0;
textbox.SelectionLength = textbox.Text.Length;`

I dont want to put it this code in each textbox_enter event of my textboxes. Is there a way so that in all of my textboxes in a form. It will always be auto highlighted?

Comment: Customizing a control by deriving your own class from the control base class is an important technique in Winforms.  [Look here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9548999/17034).  After you build your project, you'll find the new control on the top of the toolbox.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Btw. I updated it and set the border style to none. Now, how can I draw another border but this time, just one border on the bottom. how to do this? tried overriding on paint but its not doing anything. Trying to create like a flatstyle textbox where it only has border on the the bottom side.

Comment: TextBox does not support custom painting, nor will it leave enough room to draw anything extra.  You can fake it by letting the parent draw the border.

Comment: Oh ok. thanks. guess ill have to do the border manually on design. anyway, thanks a lot. you are a great help. wish you could have posted your commend on the answer so i could mark it.

Answer (score 0):

Make a "general" textbox_enter event implementation and use it for all textboxes. Cast the sender parameter to a textbox and work your magic.

```
private void textBox_Enter(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    if (sender is TextBox textbox)
    {
        textbox.SelectionStart = 0;
        textbox.SelectionLength = textbox.Text.Length;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah but that sill requires me to do it in every textbox. What i want is to do it only one time and will work on all the textboxes in a form.